# Failed building wheel for duckdb in my system

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am getting the error message while installing duckdb

```
pip install duckdb
```

the error message is

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for duckdb   Running setup.py clean for
> duckdb Failed to build duckdb ERROR: Could not build wheels for
> duckdb, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

how to get solve this issue?

want to install duckdb in my laptop.

Comment: Did you update the packager managers? Execute the `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` command before installing DuckDB.